# Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I'm going in circles with this query that I need to build. Your help is really appreciated.

I have the below tables:

Import(ID, RPTKey, Name, CountS)
Export (ID, RPTKey, Region)

I need to count or know how many times Import.RPTKey is found in Export Table.

My query below

```
UPDATE Import
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT RPTKey, COUNT(*) AS Count
 FROM Export
 GROUP BY RPTKey
 ) AS Subquery
 ON Import.RPTKey = Subquery.RPTKey
 SET Import.[CountS] = Subquery.Count;
```

My error is "Operation must use an updateable query", is there a workaround to do this? or a better way/query?

Thank you.

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually a bad design. If it can be calculated for update, it can be calculated whenever needed.